# Security settings on folder when connecting to LocalDB

Tags: c#, localdb

Trying to connect to LocalDB, but I get an exception

> Operating system error 5: "5(Access is denied.)
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Unable to open the physical file "D:\C#nonsens\learncsharp\Data access\LearnCSharp.mdf"

This is my connection string:

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\LearnCSharp.mdf;Integrated Security=True
```

I was trying to start VS on the name of Administrator, but got the same error.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: This is not a C# or LocalDB problem. Can you access the folder 'D:\C#nonsens\learncsharp\Data access\' ?

Comment: This is SQL Server permissions-related problem. Check if the instance running with admin privileges, also ensure the folder which contains MDF file is accessible with same user which currently running SQL Server instance.

Comment: Yes, I can get to folder D:\C#nonsens\learncsharp\Data access\

Comment: I can open database with SQL server Management Console that I run from the same user that I run VS.